# openvpn forward internet client to client

Tags: openvpn

I know the directive push "redirect-gateway def1" can be used to forward the traffic of a vpn server to the client.

My question is, can vpn be used to share the internet between two clients (peer-to-peer).

Comment: Yes it should be possible.  You only have to get the routing setup properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `client-to-client` directive if you want to allow connectivity between any pair of OpenVPN clients.